# Force to reload application_controller on each run with Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I am using Spork to speed up my RSpec tests. Unfortunately my `application_controller.rb` gets not reloaded on each run so that I have to restart Spork when modifying it. Is there a way to force a reload on each test run? I guess I need some additional line in `Spork.each_run`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` into the Spork.each_run block.  I would then remove this when you're done autotesting application_controller.rb, although the new delay shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but Spork is designed to automatically reload application_controller.rb without changes. So I dug into it and as mentioned in a comment in this [blog post](http://www.avenue80.com/tiny-tip-spork-not-reloading-classes/) I ran `spork --diagnose`. It lists all of the files initially loaded by spork and the backtrace for how each file was loaded. This showed me that in my app I happened to have an initializer that was referencing a subclass of ApplicationController and thus it was getting loading initially. Once I broke that dependency my application_controller.rb started reloading correctly on each test run when using Spork.